# Use all-in-one pygtk installer Windows 7 doesn't work?

Tags: python, windows-7, gtk, pygtk

I have python 2.6 installed on my Windows 7 OS.  I can run the `python` command from the command line and I enter into a python interpreter.  Now I want to install the pygtk modules.  In the past I have installed GTK+, PyGTK, PyCairo and PyGObject separately and got everything to work.  I would like to use the all-in-one installer provided on the [pygtk website](http://pygtk.org/downloads.html).  I downloaded the version from python 2.6 and the installation completed successfully.

However `import gtk` and `import pygtk` still give me the `ImportError: No module named ...`.  Does anyone know a trick to get this "all-in-one" installer to work?

Please see my answer to the post [here](http://pygtk.org/downloads.html).  Bottom line is I couldn't get the all-in-one installer to work for windows 7, but I DID get pygtk running by following the instructions given in that post.

Answer (score 2):

I am a dummy for installing the NOT all-in-one-package, (Perhaps confusingly) the one listed top on the pygtk download page (pygtk-2.24.0.win32-py2.7.exe) to which the link on the description points is the wrong installer (i.e. NOT the all in one installer).

When I corrected my mistake and used the pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.2.win32-py2.7.msi installer, everything worked just fine! Perhaps this is what happened to jeffery_the_wind too...

Answer (score 2):

The all in one installer works. Try the following link:

[pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.2.win32-py2.6.msi](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.2.win32-py2.6.msi)

On the PyGTK downloads page, clicking on the [all-in-one installer](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/) link directs you to listing of PyGTK installation binaries. Perhaps you downloaded and installed the '[pygtk-2.24.0.win32-py2.6.msi](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/pygtk-2.24.0.win32-py2.6.msi)' binary which is at the top of the listing (and probably shouldn't be here) but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help, but it may be the solution as it once was for me years ago under XP :

The all-in-one installer installs PYgtk, PYcairo, ... and allsort PYstuff, but DOES NOT install GTK+ itself.
I had to download the GTK library separately, unzip it in some folder (say "C:\GTK"), and ADD that folder in the system path, and there it was fixed !

(there is an all-in-one bundle for GTK : http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php)

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I got my install working by installing everything piecemeal, so I did not try this solution.  If someone confirms that it works I can mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: I tried that, i.e. using the gtk all-in-one installer and the GTK+ bundle. Didn't work, I still get the ImportError on import pygtk.

Comment: Also, the pygtk download page says "The all-in-one installer lets you choose the components to install so you can get a fully customized install.". I didn't get to choose - did I miss anything?